# How to configure temporal / time linear programing constraints using PuLP?

Tags: python, linear-programming, equation-solving, temporal, pulp

I am trying to solve a hypothetical linear problem using PuLP. The problem aims at minimizing the costs of an operation over a 5 year horizon while maximizing product shape and condition. The problem must generate 5 costs, one for each year while optimizing the system as a whole and the operations of each year.

```
total_cost = [(var_cost[year] + fix_cost[year] + cost_new_sensors[year]) for year in range(0,5)]
```

The `total_cost` involves maintaining three types of sensors:

```
                   # units    price_new fixed_cost_per_unit_per_yr   variable_costs_pr_yr_pr_unit
sensor_type_a      300        $50       rent + insurance             power + maint
sensor_type_b      900        $75       rent + insurance             power + maint
sensor_type_c      1500       $90       maint + insurance            -
```

- The problem must consider that for each year, the sensors are in
  better condition than the year before as well as there can't be more
  than 12% of sensors with a condition of `"Very poor"`.
- The system should be able to replace a sensor type with another or downgrade a new sensor
  purchase if the exposure isn't high. (This statement isn't related to this post)

**For `sensor_type_a`:**

- Fixed costs:

  - the rent for years 1 to 5 per unit are `[50, 55, 55, 55, 60]`
  - the insurance per unit for years 1 to 5 are `[ 1.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 2.0]`
- Variable costs:

  - power is based on number of items the sensor measured: `10+.05*each_measurement`. Price goes up by 1% per year
  - maintenance is based on `$500 for the total number of sensors + each_measurement*2.45`. Price goes up by 2% year
- exposure index indicates the status of each sensor and is based on the following table:

_

```
exposure(# of measurements)    category
<=100                          excellent
250                            good
400                            poor
>=400                          very poor
```

**For `sensor_type_b`:**

- Fixed costs:

  - the rent for years 1 to 5 per unit are `[60, 65, 65, 70, 75]`
  - the insurance per unit for years 1 to 5 are `[ 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 2.0]`
- Variable costs:

  - power is based on number of items the sensor measured: `10+.08*each_measurement`. Price goes up by 1% per year
  - maintenance is based on `$500 for the total number of sensors + each_measurement*2.65`. Price goes up by 1.5% year
- Exposure index indicates the status of each sensor and is based on the following table:

_

```
exposure(# of measurements)    category
<=200                          excellent
350                            good
500                            poor
>=500                          very poor
```

**For `sensor_type_c`:**

- Fixed costs:

  - Maintenance for all units for years 1 to 5 are `[5000, 5100, 5200, 5300, 5400]`
  - the insurance per unit for years 1 to 5 are `[ 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 2.0]`
- Exposure index indicates the status of each sensor and is based on the following table:

_

```
exposure(# of measurements)    category
<=300                          excellent
450                            good
600                            poor
>=600                          very poor
```

**My objective function/equation is one of minimization:**

```
problem = pulp.LpProblem(’Cost Minimization’, pulp.LpMinimize)
```

**My constraints:**

I am having troubles setting up the constraint functions. Here is what I am conceptually thinking of doing (mix of pseudo and python):

```
problem += sum([fixed_costs[yr][a] + var_costs[yr][a]
                               for a in sensor_type_a
                               for yr in years])

problem += sum([fixed_costs[yr][b] + var_costs[yr][b]
                               for a in sensor_type_b
                               for yr in years])

problem += sum([fixed_costs[yr][c] + var_costs[yr][c]
                               for a in sensor_type_c
                               for yr in years])

problem += sum(sensor_type_[a].condition('very poor') + \
               sensor_type_[b].condition('very poor') + \
               sensor_type_[c].condition('very poor')) <= 12%

problem += sum(sensor_type_[a].average_condition(yr) + \
               sensor_type_[b].average_condition(yr) + \
               sensor_type_[c].average_condition(yr) >=
               sensor_type_[a].average_condition(yr-1) + \
               sensor_type_[b].average_condition(yr-1) + \
               sensor_type_[c].average_condition(yr-1)
```

**Question:**

If I'm not on the right track with my pseudo+python, how can I setup my constraints properly to solve the problem?

Note that I have a table for each item filled in for each variables with the proper categories and data points

**Edit to reflect on the comments below:**

In total there are 2,700 units or locations to be measured. I have a table of the following nature:

```
   unit_ID  actual_2013   forecasted_2014   forecasted_2015   forecasted_2016   forecasted_2017
         1           25                30                40                35    50
         2          400               430               460               480    50
         n          x_1               x_2               x_3               x_4    x_5
```

The model cannot change the make up of sensor types for this year however, it should be able to model it adequately for future years. Meaning that include the cost of replacement etc, to get better sensors and a reduced overall cost.

Units are interchangeable.

Comment: You have covered the cost components very well, but I think we are missing some information. How many exposures (measurements) are needed each year? Can any type of sensor be assigned to any measurement? Once you get the `decision variables` clear, the formulation will become much easier.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan I would have the current actual exposure and a modelled results for future year exposures meaning that I would know that at sensor type a locations will have x readings and so on. For current year sensors assigned for measurements cannot change;however, they can change for future years

Comment: Could you update your problem definition? How many locations are there? Do all 1500 units of sensor type C need to be used? Are the three types interchangeable? How many exposures expected per year? We need these to formulate the LP.

Comment: @RamNarasimhan I just updated the quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach this.

#### General points

First, you want to keep the *model formulation* separate from the code implementation in PuLP or otherwise.

If you get the formulation right, it becomes much easier to implement. (You rightly mention that there are some tricky constraints in your problem.)

One final suggestion before we look at the formulation: You have quite a complex and detailed set of costs and constraints. I suggest getting the base formulation and the LP solution working, and then *layering in* the constraints and detailed costs (rentals, maintenance etc.) Otherwise, you will spend an enormous amount of time debugging and verifying your model.

### IP Formulation

#### Decision Variables vs. Inputs Constants

We have three types of sensors `s = {a, b, c}`.
We have a time horizon of 5 years = `t = {1..5}`
We have around 2700 locations `l = {1..2700}`

Main Decision variable - Deciding which sensory type goes on which location

```
Let `X_lst` be 1 if the unit at location l gets assigned a sensor of type `s` in year `t`
           0 otherwise

 Let `N_st` be the total number of sensors of type s used in year t
```

X and N are decision variables.

We are also given lots of 'constants' (These are your input tables.)

```
Let E_lt be the total number of exposures in location l in year t.
```

(Note that E_lt is given or forecast outside the problem. The IP output does *not* decide this.

One final set of decision variables are needed:

Let `Y_lst_ctype` be 1 if at the end of time period t, sensor type s in location l ends up being of condition `ctype` based on the number of exposures it sensed in that year.

ctype can be one of {Excellent, Good, Poor, VeryPoor}

By our notation Y_2b2_poor represents the decision-variable that sensor type b attached to unit 2, at the end of the 2nd year ends up in `poor` condition.

#### Constraints

Now, let's start modeling the numerous constraints that you have mentioned:

**Cover Constraint**
Every location must have a sensor in every year.
   (sum over s) X_lst = 1 for each t, for each location l.

**Total Number Constraint**
For each sensor type, in each year, we have an equation for the total number.

```
N_st = X_1st + X_2st + ... + X_2700st for each sensor type s, and for each time period t
```

(These constraints are sometimes referred to as 'definitional' constraints. They make sure that N and X are internally consistent.)

*Starting conditions*

```
N_a1 <= 300
N_b1 <= 900
N_c1 <= 1500
```

**Sensor Condition Related Constraints**

These are a bit tricky, and that's why we had to introduce so many 0/1 type `Y` variables.

Each sensor can only end up in one condition

```
Y_lst_excellent + Y_lst_good + Y_lst_poor + Y_lst_verypoor = 1
```

Now we have a write a bunch of linear constraints that ascertain the condition of the sensor based on number of exposures.

*Trick* We have to use the big-M method to make sure that the model assigns it the right condition.

For sensor type **a**

```
E_lt x X_lat <= 100 + M (1- Y_lat_good)

E_lt x X_lat <= 250 + M (1- Y_lat_poor)

E_lt x X_lat <= 400 + M (1- Y_lat_verypoor)
```

If you study this, you will see that depending on the number of exposures experienced, the correct condition gets assigned, while still keeping everything linear. (M is some big number)

Do this for the sensor types b and c also.

**Limiting Percentage to Very Poor Condition**

```
Y_1st + Y_2st + Y_3st + ... + Y_2700st <= 0.12 x Nst (for each sensor type s, year t)
```

#### Objective Function

You have already listed it, so I'll just mention the contour that the objective function will take.

Min sum_all_cots x X_lst
where the sum will have components related to rent, maintenance and replacement.

**Final Note** To be super-accurate, you also need a decision-variable that decides whether to keep or replace with new a sensor at each location.

```
R_lst = 1 if location l gets a NEW sensor of type s at the end of year t
```

And depending on the 'replace vs retail' cost trade-offs, you'd add more constraints. But the model is complicated as such, so I didn't write out those constraints.

You have to translate into your Python model and write out the formulation to see if it makes sense. Try it on a trivial problem, and keep adding more constraints and variables.

Hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks Ram for the detailed response. It's one of those responses that I will have to read multiple times before I even begin to comprehend it. I really do appreciate your effort in this

Comment: welcome. Please ask me if anything is not clear. SO is not the best medium to share an IP formulation. Start with one sensor for 2 years, get that problem working with PuLP, then grow it by adding constraints.